# Sharing Internet connection from a Linux VM to Windows

Tags: linux, networking, vmware

I'm looking for a way to share Internet connection from a Linux operation system like Ubuntu or Kali to Windows 8.1. what i'm trying to achieve is to use one of these open-source based WAN optimization softwares in [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAN_optimization) to optimize my Wireless Internet.

I've been working on this a couple of weeks and I tried to set up a host only network but I couldn't find Anywhere on the net a guide to share or forward Internet from a Linux VM to Windows 8.1. I'm using VMware workstation 11.

Comment: i'm no expert on vmware but can you clarify, Your host is windows and your VM is linux?

Comment: Yes. I have installed VMware workstation on Windows 8.1 (host) and Linux is a VM in VMware (guest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of routing/sharing/IP forwarding in linux is:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

After that, if you set the IP of the linux machine as the default gateway on any networked computers, the linux machine will forward as needed. Note that this allows forwarding betwees all interfaces.

Once you have this up and running, you should set up some basic iptables rules to prevent packets racetracking between the linux machine and any other forwarding machines, by defining which interfaces can `FORWARD` traffic from where. In addition this can provide you with a basic firewall. However, as it is not strictly required, plus I have no details regarding your setup, that would be outside of the scope of this question. For info on this, [here's a decent guide on the subject](http://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/).

Comment: I tried it but it's more complicated, i need to know the settings i should modify in VMware. can give you all of the information you need because I need a solution that can really work right now. my setup is typical and normal. a more common thing is that people use NAT in VMware to give internet from host to the VM (guest) but i want to do the opposite and give the internet from VM (guest) to host.